# Can we invoke one activity into another activity?

Tags: android, android-activity

I Mean that i want to use one activity into  another activity, Like class using create instance of that class. Is it Possible?

Comment: Yes, Obviously you can, If you want to start Activity from another activity (it is simple : [Application Fundamentals](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals.html)), Otherwise please describe your requirement, what exactly you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, I think you should use Intents to call an activity from another activity.

Call this from your Activity:

```
Intent in = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), NextActivity.class);
startActivity(in);
```

Answer (score 2):

you can do it only by saying `startActivity()`, no other go. you can't make an instance of Activity because , an Activity gets created when its `onCreate()` method gets called, but when you say `new MyActivity()` its default constructor is called and not its `onCreate()` method (which Android OS will not accept). so always say `startActivity()` or `startActivityForResult()` which are handled by `android OS`

Answer (score 2):

Write this code from where you want to run activity

```
Intent intent = new Intent(current_Activity_name.this,New_Activity_name.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
```

And add the following code into manifest file

```
<activity android:name=".New_activity_name" />
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, since an Activity is a displayable-window, the appropriate concept would be that one Activity can be "launched" from another. This is how you achieve that:

```
Intent i = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);
CurrentActivity.this.startActivity(i);
```

This code snippet can launch `NewActivity` from any point in the `CurrentActivity` code, for example, an 'OnClickListener'.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. This is achieved through Intents.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this.getApplication(), TARGET_ACTIVITY_NAME.class);
//To add data use intent.putExtra(NAME,VALUE);
intent.setData(data.getData());
try
{
    startActivity(intent); // This ll launch the TARGET_ACTIVITY_NAME
}       
catch(Exception e)
{
}
```

For more information refer this [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Shash